# WiFi data protection from landlord / Router as encrypted repeater?

Tags: encryption, wifi, data-protection, access-point, piracy-protection

I have a spare router lying around. In our house, we’re using our landlords WiFi and we’re a bit sketched out to allow them to read all our visited websites and whatnot. 
So there are basically two ideas.

A) use one of the many VPNs to undermine this

B) (and this would be easier for having guests for example,) setting up a second router to basically mimic a repeater but with a layer of encryption. Would that work? 
Could we connect to this second WiFi network, encrypt every data package, so our landlord doesn’t get to read anything?

Thanks for every input/idea!

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Maybe read the help for [security.se] to see if it would be on-topic there?

Comment: Step 1: Buy an OpenWRT compatible router & flash OpenWRT firmware, Step 2: Buy OpenVPN compatible VPN solution and Step 3: Setup OpenVPN tunnel on router. That's all folks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A) use one of the many VPNs to undermine this

Yes, effectively this is the only way

> B)... setting up a second router to basically mimic a repeater but with a layer of encryption.

Point B alone won't give you full privacy without point A. I mean - even with an additional router it's posible to see DNS queries (dnssec is still not common) and target IP addresses.

As Maarten already commented, combination of both (=having a router with VPN connection) would give you ensurance the all the connections are confidential (up to the VPN endpoint)